# TaskCompletionSource usage in IO Async methods

Tags: c#, taskcompletionsource

The implementation of the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` method in `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` is as follows:

```
    public override Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        Bid.CorrelationTrace("<sc.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync|API|Correlation> ObjectID%d#, ActivityID %ls\n", ObjectID);
        SqlConnection.ExecutePermission.Demand();   

        TaskCompletionSource<int> source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        CancellationTokenRegistration registration = new CancellationTokenRegistration();
        if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled) {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                source.SetCanceled();
                return source.Task;
            }
            registration = cancellationToken.Register(CancelIgnoreFailure);
        }

        Task<int> returnedTask = source.Task;
        try {
            RegisterForConnectionCloseNotification(ref returnedTask);

            Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(BeginExecuteNonQueryAsync, EndExecuteNonQueryAsync, null).ContinueWith((t) => {
                registration.Dispose();
                if (t.IsFaulted) {
                    Exception e = t.Exception.InnerException;
                    source.SetException(e);
                }
                else {
                    if (t.IsCanceled) {
                        source.SetCanceled();
                    }
                    else {
                        source.SetResult(t.Result);
                    }
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.Default);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            source.SetException(e);
        }

        return returnedTask;
    }
```

Which I would summarize as:

> 1. Create `TaskCompletionSource<int> source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();`
> 2. Create a new task using `Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync`, using the APM "Begin/End" API
> 3. Invoke `source.SetResult()` when the task finishes.
> 4. Return `source.Task`

What is the point of using `TaskCompletionSource` here and why not to return the task created by `Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync()` directly? This task also has the result and exception (if any) wrapped.

In C# in a Nutshell book, in the *Asynchronous Programming and Continuations* section, it states:

> In writing Delay, we
>   used TaskCompletionSource, which is a standard way to implement “bottom-level”
>   I/O-bound asynchronous methods.
>
> For compute-bound methods, we use Task.Run to initiate thread-bound concurrency.
>   Simply by returning the task to the caller, we create an asynchronous method.

Why is it that the compute-bound methods can be implemented using `Task.Run()`, but not the I/O bound methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for a definitive answer, you would have to ask the author of the code. Barring that, we can only speculate. However, I think it's reasonable to make some inferences with reasonable accuracy…

> What is the point of using TaskCompletionSource here and why not to return the task created by Task.Factory.FromAsync() directly?

In this case, it appears to me that the main reason is to allow the implementation to deregister the registered callback `CancelIgnoreFailure()` before the task is actually completed. This ensures that by the time the client code receives completion notification, the API itself has completely cleaned up from the operation.

A secondary reason might be simply to provide a complete abstraction. I.e. to not allow *any* of the underlying implementation to "leak" from the method, in the form of a `Task` object that a caller might inspect or (worse) manipulate in a way that interferes with the correct and reliable operation of the task.

> Why is it that the compute-bound methods can be implemented using `Task.Run()`, but not the I/O bound methods?

You *can* implement I/O bound operations using `Task.Run()`, but why would you? Doing so commits a thread to the operation which, for an operation that would not otherwise require a thread, is wasteful.

I/O bound operations generally have support from an I/O completion port and the IOCP thread pool (the threads of which handle completions of an arbitrarily large number of IOCPs) and so it is more efficient to simply use the existing asynchronous I/O API, rather than to use `Task.Run()` to call a synchronous I/O method.

Comment: Can I say that using TaskCompletionSource is actually to unify the output of the method, so the exception is flatten, the result is set, etc. In this case, the threading mechnism inside the method can be anything.

Comment: _"the threading mechnism inside the method can be anything"_ -- as long as the method operates asynchronously, yes. Use of TCS here allows the public method to be an _abstraction_ of whatever actually occurs within, ensuring that the caller is not dependent on, nor even aware of, the specific implementation details (i.e. good implementation-hiding practices).